# Scrapy deltafetch installation

Tags: python, scrapy, berkeley-db

While install scrapy-deltafetch using

```
pip install scrapy-deltafetch
```

I hit a bump:

```
PS C:\python\Scripts> pip install bsddb3 --no-cache-dir
Collecting bsddb3
  Downloading bsddb3-6.2.5.tar.gz (237kB) 100%
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ui_ns07z\bsddb3\setup.py", line 42, in <module>
    import setup3
     File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ui_ns07z\bsddb3\setup3.py", line 382, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(incdir, 'db.h'), 'r') as f :
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db/include\\db.h'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ui_ns07z\bsddb3\
```

I have installed berkley db x86 for windows and tried installation again by ignoring pip cache directory. The problem still exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: The other way to do it is by downloading package file, '.whl' paste it in `C:\python\Scripts` folder. Then run `pip install {package_filename}.whl`.

Comment: This may be cause by an old pip version. Try to upgrade it

Comment: Thank you @has!! That worked perfectly.
Found the binaries here for anyone who needs them:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bsddb3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @has:

The other way to do it is by downloading package file, `.whl` paste it in `C:\python\Scripts` folder. Then run `pip install {package_filename}.whl`

I found the windows binaries here for anyone who needs them:
`http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs`